# Sorting list in Ansible in natural alphanumeric order

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Is there a way to sort a list in Ansible or Jinja in a natural way?

For example this is the list

```
test
test123
test12
test5
test1234test
test22te
```

And I need it to take in account the numbers as whole not as individual so `test12` is under `test5` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the list

```yaml
  l1:
    - test
    - test123
    - test12
    - test5
    - test1234test
    - test22te
```

Create a list with an attribute *index* of type integer, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l2: "{{ l2|default([]) +
                [{'index': (_index|length > 0)|ternary(_index|int, 0),
                  'name': item}] }}"
      loop: "{{ l1 }}"
      vars:
        _regex: '^test(\d*)\D*$'
        _replace: '\1'
        _index: "{{ item|regex_replace(_regex, _replace) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ l2|sort(attribute='index')|
                    map(attribute='name')|
                    list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - test
  - test5
  - test12
  - test22te
  - test123
  - test1234test
```

Without iteration, declare the variables

```yaml
  _regex: '^test(\d*)\D*$'
  _replace: '\1'
  _index: "{{ l1|map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|map('int')|list }}"
  l2: "{{ dict(_index|zip(l1))|
                      dict2items|
                      sort(attribute='key')|
                      map(attribute='value')|
                      list }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  l2:
  - test
  - test5
  - test12
  - test22te
  - test123
  - test1234test
```

---

Example of a complete  playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    l1:
      - test
      - test123
      - test12
      - test5
      - test1234test
      - test22te

    _regex: '^test(\d*)\D*$'
    _replace: '\1'
    _index: "{{ l1|map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|map('int')|list }}"
    l2: "{{ dict(_index|zip(l1))|
                        dict2items|
                        sort(attribute='key')|
                        map(attribute='value')|
                        list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: _index
    - debug:
        var: l2
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end made jinja filter "natsort_filter.py" that does what I need. Get it here if you like:

https://gitlab.privatecloud.sk/vladoportos/custom-jinja-filters

It does require natsort module for python, but than it works just fine :)

Comment: Hello I tried to follow, https://gitlab.privatecloud.sk/vladoportos/custom-jinja-filters

created filter_plugins inside role directory and install pip install natsort but noluck it gives error.
~~~
msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'natsort'
~~~

Comment: @omankame check where you run the block, if its in localhost (delegate localhost) or on the target host... try to manually import natsort in python cmd to see if its really there

Comment: Ok Will try this.